# Variable scope in a Python generator expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, generator

I have written a function which creates a dictionary mapping strings -> generator expression. The generator expression filters a list of items based on two criteria, with those two criteria being different for each generator in the dictionary.

```
def iters(types):
    iterators = {}
    for tname in types:
        inst, type = tname.split('|')
        iterators[tname] = (t for t in transactions() if t['institution_type'] == inst and t['type'] == type)
    return iterators
```

The issue I'm running into is that all of the generators are filtered according to the last values of `inst` and `type`, presumably because those two variables are re-used in each iteration of the loop. How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `inst` and `type` names are used as *closures*; by the time you are iterating over the generators, these are bound to the last values in the loop.

Create a new scope for the names; a function can do this:

```
def iters(types):
    def build_gen(tname):
        inst, type = tname.split('|')
        return (t for t in transactions()
                if t['institution_type'] == inst and t['type'] == type)
    iterators = {}
    for tname in types:
        iterators[tname] = build_gen(tname)
    return iterators
```

You could replace the last lines with a dict comprehension too:

```
def iters(types):
    def build_gen(tname):
        inst, type = tname.split('|')
        return (t for t in transactions() 
                if t['institution_type'] == inst and t['type'] == type)
    return {tname: build_gen(tname) for tname in types}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if __closure__ was the right word here, thanks for clarifying that. I was trying to determine if I could create some kind of scoped variable in python without having to create a new function

Comment: @Stankalank: Yes, `inst` and `type` are closed over names.

Comment: Follow up question, would `inst` and `type` be closed over names in a dictionary comprehension as well? I would imagine that this is the case. Something like this seems to suffer from the same problem as the for loop: `{inst: (t for t in trans if t['something'] > 0) for inst, trans in some_dictionary}`

Comment: @Stankalank: yes, generator expressions, dict comprehensions and set comprehensions are executed in a new scope. List comprehensions are not, but only in Python 2.x. In Python 3 they all use a new scope. List comprehensions were added to the language first, and only later when more comprehensions and generator expressions were added was it discovered that using a separate scope was a better idea.